# Using visitor IP as proxy in PHP cURL

Tags: php, proxy, ip, reverse-proxy, php-curl

Let say, visitor visited my website `domain.com` and his IP is recorded `172.1.1.x` and i am using this IP to fetch real time string from `example.com`

My code

```
function file_get_contents_curl($url_curl) {
    $agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); // include headers in response
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_curl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);   
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);   

    // Use the visitor's IP address as the proxy address
    $proxy_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy_address);

   // Set the X-Forwarded-For header to the visitor's IP address
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-Forwarded-For: $proxy_address"));

    // Get the content type and content
    $response_curl = curl_exec($ch);
    $header_size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
    $content_type = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);
    $data_curl = substr($response_curl, $header_size);

    // Set the content type header (MIME Type)
    header('Content-Type:' . $content_type);

    curl_close($ch);

    return $data_curl;
}

// Usage example:
$homepage = file_get_contents_curl("https://example.com");
```

Normally, cURL use my server IP address for `HTTP request` to `example.com`, I want to use visitor IP address directly to make `HTTP request` to `example.com`

Comment: Have you checked data on `$proxy_address`? as this shows that you're getting IP address of the customer from here.

Comment: @KamranAllana yes, i am getting an IP

Comment: _"I want to use visitor IP address directly to make HTTP request to example.com"_ - that is not possible. Your visitor would have to run an open proxy on their end, which is more than unlikely.

Comment: @CBroe visitor can access `example.com` through there IP using browser. Then why it won't work if i try his IP to fetch data from `example.com` using cURL?

Comment: Because you simply _can't_ just "try their IP", that is not technically possible. Using CURLOPT_PROXY would require that they have a proxy server running, and that they let you openly access it - very, very unlikely.

Comment: @CBroe got it. so, it not possible to directly get string from `example.com` using client IP or without disclosing server IP or using of paid proxy?

Comment: No, there isn't.

Comment: @CBroe What does `CURLOPT_INTERFACE` do? `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INTERFACE, $proxy_address);` Just googling and founded some forum saying to use Interface

Comment: That specifies the name of the outgoing network interface to use. (And before you ask, no, that is not going to help you here either. Any arbitrary client's computer, is not going to be a "network interface" you can just use willy-nilly either.)